# Aplicar cambios luego del reincio android

Tags: java, android

Verán, estoy haciendo un modulo Xposed y me gustaría saber cual es la forma para que se apliquen los cambios luego de que el tlf es reiniciado.

Por ejemplo si mi modulo cambia el color de la barra de notificaciones, quiero que luego que el usuario elija el color, tenga q reiniciar el tlf para que se apliquen los cambios.

Hacer los cambios en tiempo de ejecución me causa varias dificultades, ¿Cuál seria el código para eso? ¿Hay alguna función?

Comment: Que hay de hacer un [reboot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484535/runtime-exec-reboot-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada para poder reiniciar el dispositivo necesitas tener permisos **Root** para acceder a los comando del teléfono y generalmente los dispositivos comerciales no tienen esta opción activa.

Teniendo esto simplemente hacer una solicitud de comando.

```
public static void reiniciarDispositivo()
{
    try 
    {           
       Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot"});
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
       Log.d("Error ReiniciarDispositivo: "+ e);
    }
}
```

Esta es la ruta mas general sin embargo hay otras dos que son :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/xbin/su","-c","reboot"});
```

y

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","reboot"});
```

Puedes debuggear la aplicación y verificar si hay un error en la sección debug ya que ahí se envía la información de la excepción recibida por el `catch` y verificar las otras dos rutas de opción.